# Is there a visual modeling tool / language or style which supports Scala profile?

Tags: scala, modeling, domain-data-modelling, visual-modeler

> [Similarly sounding question currently active on SO is " [Is there a visual modeling language or style for the functional programming paradigm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364237/is-there-a-visual-modeling-language-or-style-for-the-functional-programming-para) " which is different then this question because another is focusing only on Functional programming paradigm and my question is looking for a modeling tool which supports combination of Object Oriented Paradigm (which independently has many well established visual modeling UML tools) and Functional Programming Paradigm together.

Is there a **visual modeling tool / language or style** which supports Scala profile (provides and includes all Scala language artifacts) or can say that it supports **the object oriented programming paradigm** and **the functional programming paradigm**, together.

For an Enterprise scale Scala project, with what modeling tool - the business analyst prepare Visual Models or any other type of model(s) for Logical (conceptual) view and Development view?

- The logical view is concerned with the functionality that the system provides to the end-users.
- The development view illustrates a system from a programmer's perspective and is concerned with software management.

> In certain circles of software development, formal modeling is a requirement, no matter how bureaucratic you consider this to be. There are several levels of involvement from different teams on the conclusion of a project and many of the people involved have no idea about the code. They don't need to have, it'd be a major hassle if that was asked of them. The formal modeling is there to assure that they'll get a better view of how things work so that they can perform their roles in the development.
>   (This paragraph is taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/users/166802/codnik)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be one available.

I have a PhD student friend who is working on formalising modelling techniques, however he is not building a PoC.