# Linux Device Drivers 3Ed File IO & How to Influence Scheduling with Explanatory UML Diagrams

Tags: linux-kernel, uml, linux-device-driver

I've used UMLet to draw some UML diagrams describing various entity relationships for each of the chapters of Linux Device Drivers 3Ed (LDD3), by Corbet, Rubini, Kroah-Hartman. The latest version of the diagrams can be found here:

[Linux Device Drivers 3Ed UML Diagrams](http://simonderekhughes.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/understanding-kernel-device-drivers-3ed.html)

I would like to ask help understanding a scheduling problem which is supported by documentation in the Non-Blocking File IO Sequence Diagram(s) at the above link, and in LDD3 on P156-158, and in particular this code snippet from scull_getwritespace() (also see P156, but this code has been updated to use mutex rather than a semaphore):

```html
/* Wait for space for writing; caller must hold device semaphore.  On
 * error the semaphore will be released before returning. */
static int scull_getwritespace(struct scull_pipe *dev, struct file *filp)
{
 while (spacefree(dev) == 0) { /* full */
  DEFINE_WAIT(wait);
  
  mutex_unlock(&dev->mutex);
  if (filp->f_flags & O_NONBLOCK)
   return -EAGAIN;
  PDEBUG("\"%s\" writing: going to sleep\n",current->comm);
  prepare_to_wait(&dev->outq, &wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
  if (spacefree(dev) == 0)
   schedule();
  finish_wait(&dev->outq, &wait);
  if (signal_pending(current))
   return -ERESTARTSYS; /* signal: tell the fs layer to handle it */
  if (mutex_lock_interruptible(&dev->mutex))
   return -ERESTARTSYS;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

and in particular:

```html
if(spacefree(dev) == 0)
  schedule();
```

The case of interest is this:

1. spacefree(dev) == 0 is true and the write process is about to call schedule().
2. before schedule() is called, the read process issues wake_up_interruptible(&dev->outq) having consumed all the buffer data so the write process should be woken up, so it can produce more data. This sets the write process state back to TASK_RUNNING.
3. the write process calls schedule() and potentially goes to sleep.

The above is done to avoid race conditions.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to modify the code/operation of the kernel so that I can guarantee that schedule() doesn't go to sleep but returns immediately from the call? I don't understand schedule() in sufficient detail to answer this question and any help would be appreciated. I think the answer is no because the scheduler gets to choose what happens next and there may be software interrupts, tasklets or signals to process.
2. Is it possible to modify the code so that I can guarantee the write process runs before the read process is re-entered? Again, I think the answer might be no but perhaps there are some possibilities with thread prioritisation.

I find the pictorial representations of the linux kernel entities very helpful in understanding the patterns in the kernel which greatly improves my coding productivity, but they are very tedious to generate by hand. In the interests of saving time has anybody else done something similar with specific reference to LDD3?

Thanks.

Comment: You effort is well intentioned, but is not a good fit for StackOverflow.  See [ask]; especially, it is not really a question on programming as much as a document review.

Comment: Question modified to include a more detailed & specific programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have had a chance to took into kernel map http://www.makelinux.net/kernel_map/