# TLA+ How to visualize the state graph

Tags: graph, visualization, tla+, tlc

I a new `TLA+` user. 
I read that the `TLA` toolbox allows us to visualize the state graph after completion of model-checking.

In order to do so dot needs to be installed which I did. 
But I didn't figure out how to launch the visualization.
Can I do it buy using the GUI or do I need to use a dedicated command line?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To visualize the state graph, you'll need to:

1. Install [Graphviz](http://graphviz.org/) on your machine (which you've already done).
2. Configure the `TLA+ Toolbox` to point to the location of the `dot` executable on your local machine: Preferences → TLA+ Preferences → PDF Viewer → Specify dot command. (On my machine, I installed graphviz with homebrew, and my command is `/usr/local/bin/dot`).
3. In your TLC model: Additional TLC Options → TLC Options → Visualize state graph after completion of model checking (check this box)

When you run your model, there will be a `State Graph` tab with a Graphviz visualization of the state graph.